Are Code Readers able to Detect Timestamps?
The 2019 Van with around 90,000 miles on it was in the repair shop for past 4months cause it was in a wreck. After gettin it back I noticed it wasn’t running good and was acting up pressing  the gas like the transmission couldn’t change gears. By the 3rd day the Van wouldn’t go over 25mph. They had the Van for 4 months so at first I thought it was from sitting. T he engine light came on and I put my code reader on it to find out it’s got a bad sensor the transmission fluid sensor which causes all the issues I’m having. I need more work done on the van under my clam at another place but I can’t drive it. It stated the part can go bad from exposure to dirt or doing work near it possible shifting it since it is on the side of the transmission. Both of those reason apply to the repair shop since they had all of it tore down sitting outside in their yard for months before working on it. They haven’t called me in days to illuminate my issue taking the Van back to fix this or at least research what’s up. It didn’t do this when they got it and the reasons it can go bad clearly provide they could babe caused it so a times stamp would be great for my situation in case the insurance company has to send someone to investigate further cuz the repair shop is not taking responsibility. On top of that we been without our handicap van for over 4months to finally get it back not running right so we still need repair work done. I would like to know what a mechanics shop code reader that are more expensive can tell a person if this has to become a lawsuit. Thanks

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
